# International Awards for Roger Apery?

Tags: reference-request, math-history

Roger Apery stunned the math community when he proved that $\zeta(3)$ is irrational, in a truly elementary fashion. I wonder if he received any international awards specifically for this achievement.

Basically, an award which specifically mentions this proof as the main reason for it. He probably received a lot of national awards in his home country, but I am curious about global awards.

Are there any such awards?

Comment: This is a throw away account from a random machine. So if your clarifying questions don't get answered, it means I have lost access to the machine.

Comment: Nothing international, it seems: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Ap%C3%A9ry#Prix_et_r%C3%A9compenses